# Windows Server 2008 R2 foundation VM unable to detect network adaptor

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I created a Windows Server 2008 R2 foundation VM on Windows Server 2008 using Hyper-V. But I am not able to connect to internet from the VM. If I goto device manager, the network adapter branch itself is missing.
I searched in google and few sites suggested I need to install the Integration Services although in one site they said Server 2008 R2 comes with integration services installed. Anyways I tried to install IntegrationServices using hyper-v but I get error dialog "error: unable to launch one of the update programs".

Any suggestions on what am I supposed to do?

Comment: good question, although I have no idea of the answer

Answer (score 2):

To expand on this, because of the EULA restriction mentioned by "A FLeener" the required Integration Components do not exist in the Foundation edition of Server 2008 R2.

The same behavior is exhibited by Windows 7 editions less than Professional.

Because Windows 7 and 2008 R2 have Integration built in, it cannot be installed separately.

The workaround is to use the "Legacy Network Adapter" but of course you miss out on all the integration goodness such as mouse passthru, SCSI adapters, dynamic memory and time synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hyper-V management console, you need to open up the Virtual Network Manager.  In there, you make a new virtual connection, binding it to a physical NIC on your server.  Ideally, this will not be the same NIC used by the host OS.  Make the connection type 'external'.  Then, open the VM's properties (while the VM is shut down) and assign it to the new virtual network you have made.

I suggest you go back and read the documentation in the Hyper-V management console and wizards again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the settings of VM in Hyper-V manager for this particular VM I see a network adapter has been already assigned. I also need to tell you that I created 3 other VMs on this host machine, all different OS (32 bit 7, 2008) and all running properly with internet access. Only Server 2008 R2 foundation is giving problem.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machine usage rights - Windows Server 2008 Foundation is licensed to run only in a physical operating system environment.